# how to replace every 6th ooccurrence blank space with new line from a file?

Tags: linux, shell

For example  if a file has  words (or strings) separated by space as show below:

```
cat bat mat ram sdk kgb fsb cia
```

this should change to new line after every 6th word and make those words separated by comma  ? not sure how to do this using awk

```
cat ,bat, mat ,ram ,sdk ,kgb (new line )
fsb ,cia
```

Comment: Please show what you have attempted, and we can help you fix your mistakes.

Comment: sed 's/ /\n/\6'  , but this edits the 6th occurrence in a single line , I want every 6th , 12th , 18th ... occurrence  to be changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a pretty tricky thing to do. Here are a few ways:

- sed: convert all whitespace to commas, then replace every 6th comma with a newline.

  ```
  sed -r 's/[[:blank:]]+/,/g; s/([^,]+(,[^,]+){5}),/\1\n/g' file
  ```
- awk, print each field and decide what separator to use for each one.

  ```
  awk '{
      for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) 
          printf "%s%s", $i, (i == NF ? "" : ( i%6 == 0 ? "\n" : ","))
      print ""
  }' file
  ```
- bash

  ```
  myjoin() { local IFS=$1; shift; echo "$*"; }
  while read -ra words; do 
      while (( ${#words[@]} > 0 )); do 
          myjoin , "${words[@]:0:6}"
          words=( "${words[@]:6}" )
      done 
  done < file
  ```
- this one's my favourite: `tr` to convert whitespace to newlines; `paste` to print 6 fields per line; `sed` to clean up trailing commas on the last line

  ```
  tr -s '[:blank:]' '\n' < file | paste -d, - - - - - - | sed '$s/,\+$//'
  ```

  This one acts differently from the others though: if your input file has 3 lines of 8 words, all the other methods will output 6 lines, odd-numered lines with 6 fields and even-numbered lines with 2 fields. This answer will print 4 lines, all having 6 fields. So, depends on your need.